# Counting relationships in many to many relationships in grails

Tags: grails, many-to-many

I have a many to many relationship in grails domain class.

```
class Book {

   static hasMany = [tags:Tag]

   static mapping = {
   }

   static constraints = {
   }

   static transients = []

   String bookTitle
}

class Tag {

   static hasMany = [books:book]
   static belongsTo = [Book]

   static mapping ={
   }
   static constraints = {
   }

   String name  
}
```

I would like to add a transient which stores if a Book has any tags.

Is there any way to do it? For instance,

```
 def hasAnyRelation
```

Eventually I need to create a criteria which displays books that have been tagged / not tagged.

Comment: For   "if a Book has any tags "  you can use: bookInstance.tags.size()>0

Comment: That's quite expensive - loading the entire collection of instances just to count them and then throw them away

Comment: is there any simpler way? and how would the criteria be?? Book.createCriteria.list() { }  ?

Answer (score 0):

Creating this type of relations is really bad grails design. Don't connect many to many relations in both ways. You can create Tag that belongs to book or many books. But book doesn't have to know about this relation. When you want to query for tagged books, you just query for tags. If you worried about performance you can always cache results.

Answer (score 0):

Try `size` restrictions of [createCriteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html), like

for tagged books

```
Book.createCriteria.list() { 
    sizeGe("tags", 1)
}
```

for non-tagged books

```
Book.createCriteria.list() { 
    sizeEq("tags", 0)
}
```

Comment: How about `isEmpty` and `isNotEmpty` instead? :)

Comment: `isEmpty` and `isNotEmpty` are AWESOME, Thanks..,.